# Объединить три списка в один

Tags: python, list, список

Каким образом можно взять три списка и превратить их в один общий список с средним значением?
Сразу видно, что они разной длинны, поэтому мне не понятно, что с этим делать. Самое очевидное - просто нарастить список нулями до самой большой длинны и посчитать среднее для каждого символа в новом списке. Но может быть, есть какое то красивое и более правильное решение?

```
a = [1,2,6,5,3,6,4,7,3,5,2,7,2,3,6,2,6]
b = [4,2,8,5,2,6,8,2,4,6,2,1,1]
c = [3,6,2,6,7,3,4,1,6,6,3,3,6,7,2,6,3,2,2]
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе ожидаемый результат. Из вопроса неочевидно что вы хотите получить...

Comment: Важно определить что будет средним если элементов не хватает. `[2, 2], [2]` -> `[2, 1]` или `[2, 2]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте zip_longest:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1,2,6,5,3,6,4,7,3,5,2,7,2,3,6,2,6]
b = [4,2,8,5,2,6,8,2,4,6,2,1,1]
c = [3,6,2,6,7,3,4,1,6,6,3,3,6,7,2,6,3,2,2]

res = [sum(x)/3 for x in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=0)]
```

получите res:

```
[2.6666666666666665, 3.3333333333333335, 5.333333333333333, 5.333333333333333, 4.0, 5.0, 5.333333333333333, 3.3333333333333335, 4.333333333333333, 5.666666666666667, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 3.0, 3.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665, 2.6666666666666665, 3.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666]
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что неправильно будет дополнять более короткие списки нулями, т. к. это испортит среднее значение. Поэтому я вижу такое решение:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a = [1,2,6,5,3,6,4,7,3,5,2,7,2,3,6,2,6]
b = [4,2,8,5,2,6,8,2,4,6,2,1,1]
c = [3,6,2,6,7,3,4,1,6,6,3,3,6,7,2,6,3,2,2]

res = [(lambda z: sum(z)/len(z))([x for x in t if x is not None]) for t in zip_longest(a, b, c)]
```

```
[2.6666666666666665,
 3.3333333333333335,
 5.333333333333333,
 5.333333333333333,
 4.0,
 5.0,
 5.333333333333333,
 3.3333333333333335,
 4.333333333333333,
 5.666666666666667,
 2.3333333333333335,
 3.6666666666666665,
 3.0,
 5.0,
 4.0,
 4.0,
 4.5,
 2.0,
 2.0]
```

Comment: Как вариант в середине `(tuple(filter(None, t)))`